# Почему хэшируется по разному в двух файлах? Password_verify

Tags: php, mysql

Вот так хэшируется и попападет в базу mysql в регистрации

```html
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$login=mb_strtolower($login);

$name=trim($name);
$lastName=trim($lastname);
$login=trim($login);
$password=trim($password);

$password=password_hash(password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(12));

$name= htmlspecialchars($name);
$lastname=htmlspecialchars($lastname);
$login=htmlspecialchars($login);
//mysql_select_db('makinson_h',$mysqli);

$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `REG` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
$result=$result->fetch_assoc();
if(!empty($result)) exit ("2"); /*Такой пользователь уже есть*/

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `REG`(`name`, `lastname`, `login`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname', '$login', '$password')");
exit("1");/*Success*/
```

дальше при авторизации с Password_verify получаются разнные хэши к одному паролю

```html
$login=$_POST['login'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $login=trim($login);
    $password=trim($password);
    $login=mb_strtolower($login);
    
    
  //  $login=htmlspecialchars($login);
   // mysql_select_db('makinson_h',$mysqli);
 $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `REG` WHERE `login`='$login'");/*обьект*/
    $result=$result->fetch_assoc();/*массив*/
 $hash = $result['password'];
 
   if(password_verify($password,$hash))   {
    echo 'Пароль правильный!';
} else {
    echo 'Пароль неправильный.';
}
```

Вот так выгладят хэши одного и того же пароля в вардампе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему??? Где исправить?

Comment: Да это я просто показать вардамп, что типа по разному хэширует, так то у меня этой строчки нет в коде, и при отдаче в password_verify всегда false

Comment: А ты имеешь переменная $hash не нужна? ну это да, но это походу не суть важно. Всё равно не работает

Comment: ДА это понятно, делать то чего?

Comment: А как избежать искажений при записи в базу? как вообще это проверить при записи в базе, ну судя потому что хэши разные одного и того же пароля в password_verify  тут да, либо искажение, либоещё какая то хрень, я не проверяю хэшь при проверки в авторизации, этот код закоменчен, но всё равно результат разный. Отсюда вопрос, что конкретно поменять то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас две опечатки в функции password_hash, первый аргумент вы кладёте `password`, а необходимо давать переменную `$password`, и указание стоимости хеша делается вот так `array('cost'=>12)`.

```
$password=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>12));
```

Дополнительная информация https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php